# Formula to produce 1 for positive integers and 0 otherwise

Tags: c#, function, math

I have a function (f) the takes a number of items (n) and a number of columns (c) and returns the optimal layout as an array of items per column. I define optimal as being as square as possible. So f(4,4) would return [4,4,4,4], f(17,4) would return [5,4,4,4], and f(1,4) would return [1,0,0,0]. My function works correctly in all my tests, but I am looking to alter it. My desire to do this is not because I am looking increase performance. I just want to do this, because I am experimenting and want to learn different techniques.

Here is the code:

```
    public static int[] f(int n, int c){
        int[] a = new int[c];
        if(c>0 && n>=0){
            int opt = (n-(n%c))/c;
            n = n - (opt*c);
            for(int i = 0;i<a.Length;i++){
                a[i] = opt;
                if(n>0){
                    a[i]++;
                    n--;
                }
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
```

The function works by first determining the optimal number of items per col:

```
int opt = (n-(n%c))/c;
```

So f(17,4) would yield 4, f(19,4) would also yield 4, and f(3,4) would yield 0. Then the reminder is calculated:

```
n = n - (opt*c);
```

I then loop through the array (of length c) and assign a[i] equal to the optimal value. Finally, if the reminder is greater than 0 I add 1 to a[i]. This equally distributes the reminder across the array. This is the part I would like to alter.

Instead of checking if(n>0) and adding 1 to the array is there a formula I could use that might look like:

```
a[i] = opt + n*?????;
```

So n*??? would always equal 1 if n is greater than 0 and 0 if n is 0 or less?

Comment: This would probably fare better on Programmers or CompSci SE. Aside, in general, those variable names are *terrible*. Variable names should be descriptive, not letters, unless its an iteration variable.

Comment: Agree with @Bradley, but would point out that single characters may be considered appropriate for lambda arguments in some situations.  (`x => x.Age > 5`).

Comment: @KirkWoll Yes, thats the other exception (although thats *almost* still an iteration variable in the most common use cases).

Comment: Something along the lines of `((n-1) & 0x80000000) >> 31` should work. Subtract 1 to get a negative result for all values <= 0. Then use the sign bit as the result. Doesn't work for the value min(int), though.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I agree those variable names are terrible (in terms of production code someone else or future me would need to understand). However, this function is part of a larger program where multiple functions achieve the same thing (i.e. optimal column size). I am trying to show many different examples (e.g. very descriptive variable names with lots of comments versus impossible to read terse code).

Comment: @TaylorH. The problem becomes that *we* can't understand what your code does. Obviously some people have (and I'm impressed). I would try to make them a *little* better for posts here.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET If it were obligatory that everyone read and understand the code then of course it would be quite rude of me to pose a question with such a terrible setup. As you noted, several people have answered the question despite the "terrible" variable names.

Comment: @TaylorH. Its not obligatory, but remember that Stack Overflow posts are for everyone who visits the site, not just you. Having the question contain understandable code greatly increases the value for future visitors.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET My final comment is that there is more than one way to use Stack Overflow, more than the BradleyDotNET way. I will think on your advice next time I post a question though.

Comment: @TaylorH. Of course there is, and I'm not saying you have to follow it. Just trying to provide observations from reading Meta, and inform you in case you haven't received the same information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is to use an expression with the conditional operator:

```
a[i] = opt + (n > 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

`(n > 0 ? 1 : 0)` will be `1` if `n` is greater than `0`, and `0` otherwise.

---

On that note, there is a clearer and more concise way to implement your algorithm.

1. Determine the total number of items that can be distributed evenly between the slots (call this `average`). This has the value `n / c` (using integer division).
2. Determine the remainder that would be left after those are evenly distributed (call this `remainder`). This has the value `n % c`.
3. Put the value `average + 1` in the first `remainder` slots, and put `average` in the rest.

The implementation for this would be:

```
public static int[] Distribute(int total, int buckets)
{
    if (total < 0) { throw new ArgumentException("cannot be less than 0", "total"); }
    if (buckets < 1) { throw new ArgumentException("cannot be less than 1", "buckets"); }

    var average = total / buckets;
    var remainder = total % buckets;

    var array = new int[buckets];

    for (var i = 0; i < buckets; i++)
    {
        array[i] = average + (i < remainder ? 1 : 0);
    }

    return array;
}
```

And the obligatory Linq version:

```
public static int[] DistributeLinq(int total, int buckets)
{
    if (total < 0) { throw new ArgumentException("cannot be less than 0", "total"); }
    if (buckets < 1) { throw new ArgumentException("cannot be less than 1", "buckets"); }

    var average = total / buckets;
    var remainder = total % buckets;

    return Enumerable.Range(1, buckets)
                     .Select(v => average + (v <= remainder ? 1 : 0))
                     .ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a simple function which outputs `int` on a `bool` expression?

```
int IsPositive(int number)
{
    //if number is > 0 return integer one (1), else return integer zero (0)
    return number > 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

You can then use this in your code as such:

```
a[i] = opt + IsPositive(n);
//opt + 1 if n > 0, opt + 0 if n <= 0
```

**Update**: per your comment, you can just move the evaluation inline:

```
a[i] = opt + (n > 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

As an aside: you should make [@BradleyDotNET's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555416/formula-to-produce-1-for-positive-integers-and-0-otherwise/27555697#comment43537110_27555416) one of your programming mottos.

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't exactly the answer I am looking for. I don't want multiple function calls. Looking for a simple expression.

Comment: why not add it directly in the expression then? `a[i] = opt + (n > 0 ? 1 : 0);`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a formula:

`Math.Max(n - Math.Abs(n - 1), 0)`

should do the trick.
Your code should look like:

`a[i] = opt + Math.Max(n - Math.Abs(n - 1), 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Another option for a formula would be

```
Math.Max(Math.Sign(n), 0)
```

If you are looking for a mathematical formula, I'm not sure you're going to find it as the function is discontinuous at n = 0.